# Why can mathematica not solve my equation?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, equation

I can not get my head around why mathematica can not solve this equation:

```
In[22]:= Solve[1/x^12 - 2/x^6 + 1/2 (-2 + x)^2 HeavisideTheta[-2 + x] == 0]
During evaluation of In[22]:= Solve::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve. >>
Out[22]= Solve[1/x^12 - 2/x^6 + 1/2 (-2 + x)^2 HeavisideTheta[-2 + x] == 0]
```

using mathematica 9.0.1.0.

Edit:

```
In[24]:= Plot[1/x^12 - 2/x^6 + 1/2 (-2 + x)^2 HeavisideTheta[-2 + x], {x, 1, 3}]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: will do, thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 2):

FindRoot is often more aggressive

```
FindRoot[1/x^12-2/x^6+1/2(-2+x)^2 HeavisideTheta[-2+x]==0, {x, 3}]
```

and that almost instantly returns the solution.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to look for analytic solutions ( which is what `Solve` does ),
assume the step function has a value 0 or 1 , use `Solve` and check the step function assumption against the results:

```
 Select[ Solve[1/x^12 - 2/x^6 + 1/2 (-2 + x)^2  (0) == 0]  ,  
     HeavisideTheta[-2 + x /. #] == 0 & ]
```

> {{x -> -(1/2^(1/6))}, {x -> 1/2^(1/6)}}

```
 Select[ Solve[1/x^12 - 2/x^6 + 1/2 (-2 + x)^2  (1) == 0]  ,  
     HeavisideTheta[-2 + x /. #] == 1 & ]
```

> {{x -> Root[2 - 4 #1^6 + 4 #1^12 - 4 #1^13 + #1^14 &, 2]}}

Of the three solutions, the one I guess you want is the last one ,  the root of a 14th order polynomial, which you need to eval numerically anyway:

```
 N[Root[2 - 4 #1^6 + 4 #1^12 - 4 #1^13 + #1^14 &, 2] ]
```

> 2.18999